# Mongodb aggregation is slow only on Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot 2 with Spring Data and a local Mongodb 3.4.
I currently have a collection with ~200k documents, properly indexed via Spring's annotations.

I've crafted an aggregation pipeline (seen at the bottom of this post) which takes around **2000ms** to complete in: Python, Studio3T, **Spring Boot unit tests**.

When I run the very same query normally on a **deployed instance of my application(bootJar)**, it takes **8000ms** which is not acceptable for my use case and is also very weird.

The database logs report query times of ~300ms in all cases so the db is performing fine.

It is very interesting to find out why this happens since the code in a normal deployment and during unit testing is exactly the same (also using the same parameters), and therefore should be comparable in performance.

My guess goes as far as that the configuration differs between deployment and testing. I use the default settings on both environments (no specific bean declarations for mongo, just autowiring `MongoOperations` and enjoying the "Boot magic").

---

Here are some samples:

A document looks like this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b4f76696d370f30d401f246"), 
  "description" : "IoT420", 
  "timestamp" : NumberLong(1530286316), 
  "sensor" : "Temperature", 
  "value" : 30.02, 
  "class" : "net.derp.iot.piws.entities.dto.MongoMeasurementRepr"
}
```

The aggregation pipeline:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match( where( "description" ).is( filterDescription ) ),
            match( where( "sensor" ).is( sensorName ) ),
            match( where( "timestamp" ).gte( tsFrom ).lte( tsTo ) ),
            sort( Sort.Direction.ASC, "timestamp" ));
```

This aggregation returns around 120k documents.

I use `System.nanoTime()` to measure time.

---

**Update**: After removing `runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')` the time dropped to **5000ms**, which is still slower than the testing case. I suspect some sort of "validation" that gets disabled during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deploying the same jar on a linux server (with a different database), everything looks normal (query times ~2000ms). I am guessing there was a configuration conflict with my environment or something like that..

Answer (score 1):

I gone through your query and it observe you are giving timestamp criteria after two   match stages. Ideally date criteria should be first in mongo query as it narrows down the number of documents to scan for next stage.

So your aggregation query should be

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match( where( "timestamp" ).gte( tsFrom ).lte( tsTo ) ),
            match( where( "description" ).is( filterDescription ) ),
            match( where( "sensor" ).is( sensorName ) ),
            sort( Sort.Direction.ASC, "timestamp" ));
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct. 1. You can't tell without seeing the index fields order. 2. If the index starts with ts there might be many leaves to scan in order to find those that matches sensor type, a sensor is more unique and after taking the ones you need there will be much less to scan. 3. My guess is that the order in the query  order is changed by the optimizer fit the fields order in the index